# Cannot Select a Document body in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to print text to a google doc I have created using Google Apps Script, and I have the following code:

```
DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YPthft_5n5TFpnN2uqwonHtxcFmI40LOoVei7N1IdXA/edit");
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();

var x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
"p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
function CreateDoc(name) {
  DocumentApp.create(name);
}
function rightClick(document) {
  var i
  for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

    body.appendParagraph("x[i]");
  }
}
rightClick();
```

What happens is when I run anything it comes up with the error :
`TypeError: Cannot call method "getBody" of null. (line 3, file "Code")`
I do not understand why it does this or how to fix it. If you could help me fix it that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a document by using openByUrl doesn't make it the active document.

Change the first line to

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YPthft_5n5TFpnN2uqwonHtxcFmI40LOoVei7N1IdXA/edit");
```

Remove the second line.

Comment: That fixed it instantly. Then I had to fix my for loop but now it works.